# Need help understanding Linear Algebra Proof (Sylvester's Law of Nullity).

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

Link to proof : https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9ghf.jpg

We're proving Theorem 2.1 (i).  Proof begins at the bottom of pg 19.  I can follow until the top of pg 21 when they say "the linear independence of $u_1,\ ...\ ,u_n$ implies that $c_{r+1} =\ ...\ =c_n = 0$.

The only obvious way I could see that being the case were if we knew that $\sum_{t=1}^r a_tu_t = 0$ and I'm pretty sure that's not something we're allowed to assume here, so there must be something I'm missing.

Also I'm not confident in how the former implies the following statement "Hence $T(u_{r+1}),\ ...\ ,T(u_n)$ do in fact constitute a basis of rng T".

PS : note on notation - I don't know if this notation is common or what, but in this book $L(U,V)$ denotes "the totality of linear transformations on U to V".

Comment: The subscripts on the LHS is from $r+1$ to $n$, and that on the RHS is from 1 to $r$!

Comment: Yes I know.  I don't see what you're getting at though can you be explicit?

Comment: Write out fully. you have $a_1 u_1 + \cdots + a_r u_r = c_{r+1} u_{r+1} + \cdots + c_n u_n$. Rearranging you have $a_1u_1 + \cdots + a_ru_r + (-c_{r+1})u_{r+1} + \cdots + (-c_n) u_n =0$. Now apply linear independence.

Comment: Yep I get it.  Thank you.